# Attempting to Join 3 tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables that are joined.  I almost have the solution but there seems to be one small problem going on here.  Here is statement:

```
SELECT items.item,
COUNT(ratings.item_id) AS total,
COUNT(comments.item_id) AS comments,
AVG(ratings.rating) AS rate
FROM `items`
LEFT JOIN ratings ON (ratings.item_id = items.items_id)
LEFT JOIN comments ON (comments.item_id = items.items_id)
WHERE items.cat_id = '{$cat_id}'  AND items.spam < 5
GROUP BY items_id ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM items.item) ASC;");
```

I have a table called items, each item has an id called items_id (notice it's plural).  I have a table of individual user comments for each item, and one for ratings for each item.  (The last two have a corresponding column called 'item_id').

I simply want to count comments and ratings total (per item) separately.  With the way my SQL statement is above, they are a total.

- note, total is the total of ratings. It's a bad naming scheme I need to fix!

UPDATE:  'total' seems to count ok, but when I add a comment to 'comments' table, the COUNT function affects both 'comments' and 'total' and seems to equal the combined output.

Comment: So what's the problem? How to join? How to count? How to produce json?

Comment: COUNT(comments.item_id) AS comments  does not seem to be executing right.  Is my SQL logic sound? Are there any obvious errors I have made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you're counting results of all 3 tables joined. Try:

```
SELECT i.item,
r.ratetotal AS total,
c.commtotal AS comments,
r.rateav AS rate
FROM items AS i
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT item_id, 
    COUNT(item_id) AS ratetotal, 
    AVG(rating) AS rateav 
    FROM ratings GROUP BY item_id) AS r 
ON r.item_id = i.items_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT item_id, 
    COUNT(item_id) AS commtotal 
    FROM comments GROUP BY item_id) AS c
ON c.item_id = i.items_id
WHERE i.cat_id = '{$cat_id}'  AND i.spam < 5
ORDER BY TRIM(LEADING 'The ' FROM i.item) ASC;");
```

In this query, we make the subqueries do the counting properly, then send that value to the main query and filter the results.

Comment: I see what youre doing and I like it.  Keep getting a 'mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result'.  Trying to get past that to see if this works for what I was asking.

Comment: That was it!   I just changed "i" to "items" and your answer works perfect!  Didn't even realize you can do sub-queries.  Thanks for the insight!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to Alias your 'items' table. `FROM items AS i` would also fix it. Subqueries come in very handy when you're asking your DB for increasingly complicated things.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is a cardinality issue. Try `COUNT(distinct comments.item_id)`